# In Azure Data Factory, can I pass data from dataset as input to the Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am able to copy data between two 'Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB' datasets using Azure Data Factory pipeline.

Now, I would like to transform the data using Azure Function before the data is pushed to the destination dataset. Is this possible in Azure Data Factory? If so, is there a documentation that I can refer to?

I thought this should have been a supported use case. Each record from the source dataset, considering it is in JSON format could be forwarded as-is in the request body to the HTTP triggered function, and the JSON response of this function would be available for use later in the pipeline.

I tried setting the body of the HTTP triggered function as the `@activity('Copy Activity').output` but the 'Copy Activity' output contains the metadata about the activity execution, not the dataset records that I am looking for. I also gave a try to dataflows but could not get started as 'Azure Cosmos DB for Mongo DB' is [not a supported data store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview#supported-data-stores). There is not much information that can help with my scenario in the [Azure Function activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) documentation page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to pass the dataset from ADF to Azure function, we can use lookup activity. Lookup will give an array of objects as the output.

But in this case, the source dataset(`Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB`) doesn't support lookup activity. As per the documentation, it only supports copy activity. You can raise a feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c) to add it for lookup.

As a workaround, you can try the below approach if you have access ADLS or Blob storage accounts.

- First copy the **Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB** data to Blob or ADLS JSON file using copy activity.
- Now, Use lookup activity on the JSON file. Based on the lookup activity output JSON, use the dynamic expression `@activity('lookup1').output.value` or `@activity('lookup1').output.value[0]` to get the required JSON.
- After lookup, pass this JSON to your Azure function as per your requirement.

Also, you can get the JSON of the `Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB` dataset, using this [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/2021-07-01-preview/mongo-db-resources/get-mongo-db-collection?tabs=HTTP).

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/{accountName}/mongodbDatabases/{databaseName}/collections/{collectionName}?api-version=2021-07-01-preview
```

- First, get the bearer token using one **Web activity** in ADF with Service principal.
- After that, use that bearer token and the above REST API in **another Web activity** to get the MongoDB collection under an Azure Cosmos DB database.
- You will get a JSON as web activity response like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/2021-07-01-preview/mongo-db-resources/get-mongo-db-collection?tabs=HTTP#cosmosdbmongodbcollectionget).
- Identify your required JSON in that and pass it your Azure function.

**NOTE:** These method only works when your source data size is less than 4 MB. Both Lookup activity and web activity output limitation is 4 MB (5000 rows) only. If your data is more than that, then its better to connect the Source in the Azure function code itself rathen than passing it from ADF dataset.